MSVC fatal error LNK2001: 1 unresolved externals
I know there is a lot of similar questions, but nevertheless I couldn't get rid of this looking so simple error no matter what I do:

there is an old library OldLib written mostly in c. and I want to "inject" a small code to slightly change its behavior

I created a header inject.h with one line:
extern __declspec(dllexport) char FilePath[255];

Then a source file inject.c :
char FilePath[255] = "";

Added link to the file inject.h in the main header of the old library and started using FilePath in its sources.

After that I created an MSVC project for convenience working via cmake:



add_library(OldLib STATIC)
add_library(MyDll SHARED)
target_sources(OldLib
# a lot of OldLib sources 
#....
  PRIVATE inject.h
  PRIVATE inject.c
  )
target_sources(MyDll 
  PRIVATE inject.h
  PRIVATE MyDll.h   
# MyDll.cpp sets FilePath with some value
  PRIVATE MyDll.cpp
  )
target_link_libraries(MyDll 
  PRIVATE OldLib
)



and here I am stuck always getting link error:


MyDll.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char *
FilePath" (?FilePath@@3PADA) [MyDll.vcxproj]
Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
_FilePath


I tried changing inject.cpp to inject.c and vice versa, removing and adding __declspec(dllexport), creating a dll without static library adding all OldLib code sources directly to MyDll project, but the error still persists.

What am I doing wrong?

You need a __declspec(dllimport) when building the consuming library, not __declspec(dllexport). Did you try that?

Yes I tried that too, the result is absolutely the same. The static library is compiled fine in both cases, with __declspec(dllimport)and __declspec(dlliexport) and I dont know what is the proper one, maybe that depends on where I put inject.c either in OldLib or in MyDll? Maybe inject.h should differ for both projects? If one lib exports the symbol, another one imports it. Hmm I 'll test it

At last I made it using the very helpful answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025157/1886550. So I createsd two header files, one  with extern __declspec(dllexport) char FilePath[255]; I added to the OldLib and another one with extern "C" char FilePath[255];`in MyDll project

Answered by this

Does this answer your question? What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?
